# Sqlite error in while appending file

Tags: swift

I am ne to iOS developer i want to one thing that when i connect Sqlite with Xcode then after appending the code in nsobject class the error comes second line that **instance member documents cannot be used type of class name**

Here is code-

```
   let documents = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
    var db: COpaquePointer = nil

if sqlite3_open(fileURL, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(fileURL)")
        return db
    } else {
        print("Unable to open database. Verify that you created the directory described " +
            "in the Getting Started section.")
}
```

Please resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you're trying to declare `fileURL` outside of a method. If this is a property, you can't reference `documents` like that. So, either make this a local variable of your method, or collapse these two declarations into a single statement:

In Swift 3:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")!
```

In Swift 2:

```
let fileURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    .URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")!
```

That avoids referencing `documents` at all.

As an aside, you can't pass `fileURL` to the `sqlite3_open` function. You should use `fileURL.path` (or, in Swift 2, `fileURL.path!`).

Comment: Thanku!! am also getting the error in this  sqlite3_open(fileURL.path!,&db)

Comment: error is Linker command failed with exit code and sqlite3_open referenced from

Comment: @Bansal - You have to add `libsqlite3.tbd` to your list of "linked frameworks and libraries" on the target settings screen.

Comment: you should try it when someone answer your question..can we talk directly other than stack overflow

Comment: so that i can better understand problem and some time might be solve your problem

Comment: @Bansal usually it's best to ask a few questions in the comment section + searching other places online and then eventually if needed come back here and continue a chat discussion...

Comment: if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "Select * from Ankit", -1, &db, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
        }

Comment: i am using this for fetch the data but it shows out of memory can you resolve it

Comment: It shows "out of memory" when `db` is `nil`. That might happen because that third parameter is the `statement` and because you used `db`, it could have `nil`-ed it: `sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "Select * from Ankit", -1, &statement, nil)`. If that doesn't do it, make sure `sqlite3_open` succeeded and that `db` is not `nil`.

Comment: hello rob!! one thing i want to ask when i perform operation of CRUD then these method is implemented in NSObject class  then it is giving me error